# SQL Server : dymanic SQL error: 'CREATE VIEW' must be the first statement in a query batch

Tags: sql-server, dynamic-sql

I wrote a stored procedure with dynamic SQL which throws an error when I call it when arguments:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('[dbo].[find_most_frequent]') IS NOT NULL
  DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[find_most_frequent]
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[find_most_frequent] 
        @table_in VARCHAR(100),
        @table_out VARCHAR(100),
        @col_group VARCHAR(100),
        @col_2 VARCHAR(100) 
AS
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(4000);

    SET @sql =
    --start of code
    'USE CTR
GO

IF OBJECT_ID(N''[dbo].[two_columns]'', N''V'') IS NOT NULL
    DROP VIEW [dbo].[two_columns];

IF OBJECT_ID(N''[dbo].[count_in_group]'', N''V'') IS NOT NULL
    DROP VIEW [dbo].[count_in_group];

IF OBJECT_ID(N''[dbo].[rank_in_group]'', N''V'') IS NOT NULL
    DROP VIEW [dbo].[rank_in_group];

IF OBJECT_ID(N''[dbo].[most_frequent_in_group]'', N''V'') IS NOT NULL
    DROP VIEW [dbo].[most_frequent_in_group];
GO

CREATE VIEW [dbo].[two_columns] AS
SELECT ' +
        @col_group +
        ' ,' + @col_2 +
    ' FROM ' + @table_in +
'
GO

CREATE VIEW [dbo].[count_in_group] AS
SELECT  DISTINCT
        *
        ,COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY ' + @col_group + ', ' + @col_2 + ') AS freq
    FROM [dbo].[two_columns]
GO  

CREATE VIEW [dbo].[rank_in_group] AS
SELECT  *
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ' + @col_group + ' ORDER BY freq DESC) AS rank_in_group
    FROM [dbo].[count_in_group]
GO

CREATE VIEW [dbo].[most_frequent_in_group] AS
SELECT *
    FROM [dbo].[rank_in_group]
    WHERE rank_in_group = 1
GO

SELECT *
    INTO ' + @table_out + 
    ' FROM [dbo].[most_frequent_in_group]
GO'
--end of code    
    print @sql
    EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @sql
END 
GO

--call it
EXEC [dbo].[find_most_frequent]
        @table_in = '[dbo].[table_1]'
        ,@table_out = '[dbo].[table_out]'
        ,@col_group = '[col_A]'
        ,@col_2 = '[col_B]' 
GO
```

Error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 81
>   Incorrect syntax near 'GO'.
>   Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 91
>   Incorrect syntax near 'GO'.
>   Msg 111, Level 15, State 1, Line 93
>   'CREATE VIEW' must be the first statement in a query batch.
>   Msg 111, Level 15, State 1, Line 97
>   'CREATE VIEW' must be the first statement in a query batch.
>   Msg 111, Level 15, State 1, Line 104
>   'CREATE VIEW' must be the first statement in a query batch.
>   Msg 111, Level 15, State 1, Line 110
>   'CREATE VIEW' must be the first statement in a query batch.
>   Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 114
>   Incorrect syntax near 'GO'.

The line number is useless, since they are lines after the end of my code...

In the procedure I printed @sql to take a look. I copy the printed code and paste it into another query, it worked. - So I totally don't know how to debug it now....

```
USE CTR
GO

IF OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[two_columns]', N'V') IS NOT NULL
    DROP VIEW [dbo].[two_columns];

IF OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[count_in_group]', N'V') IS NOT NULL
    DROP VIEW [dbo].[count_in_group];

IF OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[rank_in_group]', N'V') IS NOT NULL
    DROP VIEW [dbo].[rank_in_group];

IF OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[most_frequent_in_group]', N'V') IS NOT NULL
    DROP VIEW [dbo].[most_frequent_in_group];
GO

CREATE VIEW [dbo].[two_columns] AS
SELECT [hash_vcc] ,[legal_name] FROM [dbo].[ctr_vendor_pay]
GO

CREATE VIEW [dbo].[count_in_group] AS
SELECT  DISTINCT
        *
        ,COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY [hash_vcc], [legal_name]) AS freq
    FROM [dbo].[two_columns]
GO  

CREATE VIEW [dbo].[rank_in_group] AS
SELECT  *
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [hash_vcc] ORDER BY freq DESC) AS rank_in_group
    FROM [dbo].[count_in_group]
GO

CREATE VIEW [dbo].[most_frequent_in_group] AS
SELECT *
    FROM [dbo].[rank_in_group]
    WHERE rank_in_group = 1
GO

SELECT *
    INTO [dbo].[hashvcc_2_legalname] FROM [dbo].[most_frequent_in_group]
GO
```

Can somebody help please? Any help's appreciated. Thanks

**UPDATE**:

I split each `CREATE VIEW` into different strings, and EXEC them separately.
- Use `BEGIN` `END` to wrap each `CREATE VIEW` doesn't work.

Now still this piece throws error:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[most_frequent_in_group] AS
SELECT *
    FROM [dbo].[rank_in_group]
    WHERE rank_in_group = 1

SELECT *
    INTO [dbo].[hashvcc_2_legalname]
    FROM [dbo].[most_frequent_in_group]
```

Error:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'.

It works when I run `CREATE VIEW` and `SELECT` separately.

Got answer: `VIEW` has to be the only statement in a batch - thanks to @ZLK

Comment: Unfortunately, since `GO` isn't actually T-SQL (see Remarks here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188037.aspx), you would have to consider an alternative like breaking up each part and executing them separately.

Comment: Thank you @ZLK! Does BEGIN END work?

Comment: In dynamic sql? Yes... But not for creating views and other such things that are required to be at the start of a batch.

Comment: I see. yeah I tested BEGIN END doesn't fix the error of `must be the first statement in a query batch.`

Comment: hi @ZLK sorry to bother again. Could you take a look at the update in OP. why `SELECT` can't follow `CREATE VIEW xxx AS SELECT ..  FROM ...`? Thanks

Comment: The view should be the only statement in a batch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About [GO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188037.aspx#languageReferenceRemarksToggle):

> GO is not a Transact-SQL statement; it is a command recognized by the
>   sqlcmd and osql utilities and SQL Server Management Studio Code
>   editor.

Split your query into separate requests:

```
EXEC sp_executesql N'
USE CTR

IF OBJECT_ID(N''[dbo].[two_columns]'', N''V'') IS NOT NULL
    DROP VIEW [dbo].[two_columns];
IF OBJECT_ID(N''[dbo].[count_in_group]'', N''V'') IS NOT NULL
    DROP VIEW [dbo].[count_in_group];
IF OBJECT_ID(N''[dbo].[rank_in_group]'', N''V'') IS NOT NULL
    DROP VIEW [dbo].[rank_in_group];
    IF OBJECT_ID(N''[dbo].[most_frequent_in_group]'', N''V'') IS NOT NULL
    DROP VIEW [dbo].[most_frequent_in_group];'

EXEC sp_executesql N'
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[two_columns] AS
SELECT [hash_vcc] ,[legal_name] FROM [dbo].[ctr_vendor_pay]'

...
```

And so on.

Comment: I see. Thank you@Backs! Does BEGIN END work? Is N before the string necessary? Thanks-

Comment: @YZhang `BEGIN` and `END` is valid TSQL syntax. `N` means that string is unicode. Stored procedure `sp_executesql` works with unicode only